# Active Admin and Devise: current_user and user_signed_in? undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

So I was implementing a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` in order to check a custom `enabled` attribute for a user, which would kill their session and return them to the login page if an Admin had disabled their account.

I kept running into errors such as:

`undefined method current_user`
and
`undefined method user_signed_in?`

I googled around a bit and tried other solutions from StackOverflow (see below), and it did not work.

Add the following to `application.rb`:

`config.action_controller.include_all_helpers = false`

Answer (score 2):

After banging my head for a bit, I remembered reading something in the Active Admin config file, `active_admin.rb` about setting a helper method for the admin user.

Note: Instead of using Devise's default `User` model, I am using Active Admin's `AdminUser` instead.

So if you look into the `active_admin.rb` file you'll see:

`# This setting changes the method which Active Admin calls`

`# (within the application controller) to return the currently logged in user.`

`config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user`

So here Active Admin is overriding Devise's `current_user` helper!

Then it dawned on me:

Instead of `current_user`, use: `current_admin_user`

And instead of `user_signed_in?`, use: `admin_user_signed_in?`

Boom, done!